# MySQL: user has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I know this is well talked topic, but in my case is a little bit different. I have a SaaS service where each subscription has its own database.

By querying `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in my 25 databases, I get the same result in every one:

[image]

All databases seem to not have any connection whatsoever, yet I still receive the error:

> User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

I'm using a shared hosting CPanel and the limit `max_connections` is 150.

[image]

How is it possible that the `max_connections` has been reached when the `processlist` shows that nothing is being query? Plus, how do I reset the connections without the help of the hosting?

This is a PHP with CodeIgniter framework project.

Comment: What does `max_user_connections` show?

Comment: @aynber shows 15

Comment: Make sure you're not using the same user for every database. 15 means there's a max of 15 connections per user. You may not be seeing all of the simultaneous connections if they hit at once then disappear.

Comment: @aynber I just tested with a different user just for one database and error persists (for the new user)

Comment: Test mysqli_get_client_stats()[active_connections] - results might be unexpected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**.

After contacting the hosting, they incremented the `max_user_connections` to 20, but the problem still persists. The project has been running for more than a year without a problem, so it was confusing to me.

I used this hook https://github.com/ozanmora/ci_log_query to print all the queries being done and it was clear that I was connecting to multiple models that weren't being used.

For example in all my classes (and controllers) I was loading all the models in the constructor and some of this models were only used in a certain function, therefore they were consuming resources without being used.

Example:

```
public function _construct()
{
    $this->load->model('a_model');
    $this->load->model('b_model');
    $this->load->model('c_model');
    $this->load->model('d_model');
    $this->load->model('e_model');
}
```

And I only call them in some functions, like:

```
public function test()
{
    $this->a_model->doSometing();
    $this->b_model->doSometing();
}

public function test2()
{
    $this->c_model->doSometing();
}

public function test3()
{
    $this->d_model->doSometing();
}
```

The solution to avoid loading unnecessary models/connections is to only load the models when needed. Although this was working previously without any problem, I end up fixing all my controllers/classes (which is quite a bit). The connections were drastically reduced and now its working.

```
public function _construct()
{

}

public function test()
{
    $this->load->model('a_model');
    $this->load->model('b_model');
    
    $this->a_model->doSometing();
    $this->b_model->doSometing();
}

public function test2()
{
    $this->load->model('c_model');

    $this->c_model->doSometing();
}

public function test3()
{
    $this->load->model('d_model');

    $this->d_model->doSometing();
}
```